# Fix the bogus modification time of some mkv files based on that of srt files with the same root name

Tags: ubuntu, date, touch

I found around 50 mkv files with modification time in the future (year 2098 and 2097). I see that .srt files with the same name carry the right date and are located in the same subfolder as each mkv file.

How would you issue a `touch` command to read the oldest srt and change the last modified date of the mkv in the same subfolder to that date?

> ```
> home/incoming/media/berlin.festival.2019/berlin.festival.2019.mkv 
> home/incoming/media/Exit.festival.2022/Exit.festival.2022.mkv
> ```

```
$ for f (*/.mkv) touch -r $f:r.srt
```

-- $f doesn't catch them only catch them in the root of media folder

I tried something like

```
$ for file in $(find /home/loop/test/*.mkv -type f) do touch -r $f:r.srt -- $f
```

in my test folder but it's not working.

Ubuntu is the operating system.

From [Change the last modification time of subfolders to that of the oldest file inside](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/759058), I fixed the dates of folder with

```
for dir in /home/loop/test/*(NF); do
  oldest=( $dir/*.(|srt|)(N.Om[1]) )
  if (( $#oldest )) touch -r $oldest -- $dir
done
```

`ls -l` has perfect date now for the folders because I already fixed it by using dates from srt files.

But I would like to change date of mkv files inside of subfolders based on date of srt files.

> ```
> /home/loop/test # ls -l  
> drwxrwxrwx 2 loop loop 4096 Jul 23 2019 berlin.festival.2019 
> drdrwxrwx 2 loop loop 4096 Jan 5 2019 Belgum.2018
> drwxrwxrwx 2 loop loop 4096 Feb 21 2020 Denmark.2019 
> drwxrwxrwx 2 loop loop 4096 Oct 3 2020 Exit.festival.2022
> ```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Care to share? Because it's not clear which part you cannot solve, unless you are asking somebody to code it for you.

Comment: for f (**/*.mkv) touch -r $f:r.srt -- $f doesn't catch them only catch them in the root of media folder I tried something like for file in $(find /home/loop/test/*.mkv -type f) do
touch -r $f:r.srt -- $f   in my test folder but its not working.

Comment: Thanks. I copied the the code from the comments to the question where most people will be able to see it right away. Please edit the question if needed and instead of *not working* it might be better to paste the actual error code, it's usually helpful information.

Comment: Please also tell us what operating system you are using, and show us the output of `ls -l` on the good and bad files. Do you want us to change the modification date only?

Comment: Ubuntu is the file system. I fixed dates of folder with the
for dir in /home/loop/test/*(NF); do
  oldest=( $dir/*.(|srt|)(N.Om[1]) )
  if (( $#oldest )) touch -r $oldest -- $dir
Ls -l has perfect date now for the folders because I already fixed it by using dates from srt files.
But I would like to change date of mkv files inside of subfolders based on date of srt files.

Comment: /home/loop/test # ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 2 loop loop 4096 Jul 23  2019 berlin.festival.2019
drdrwxrwx 2 loop loop 4096 Jan  5  2019 Belgum.2018
drwxrwxrwx 2 loop loop 4096 Feb 21  2020 Denmark.2019
drwxrwxrwx 2 loop loop 4096 Oct  3  2020 Exit.festival.2022
Its too big to put all output and its hard to write on the forum I don't know I'm new to the forum.

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question to answer comments and include extra information. If you put it in a comment, you cannot format it (as you can see above) and it is very easy to miss.

Comment: Ok I will  try like that

Comment: Ubuntu is NOT a filesystem. Its is the distribution of the Operating system. Your filesystem will be ext4, xfs, btrfs or similar (you can find this in /etc/fstab and in the output of the mount command).

Comment: Its ext4 I answered fast, and I somehow though he was asking whats the operating system.I didn't pay close attention on the exact wording in the question,  I don't know why is so important to punish someone because of trivial errors. Its ok thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, from within the `/home/loop/test` directory:

```
for mkv in **/*.mkv(Nms-1); do
  srt=( $mkv:r(.*|).srt(N.Om[1]) )
  if (( $#srt )) touch -r $srt -- $mkv
done
```

Would loop through all the files last `m`odified less than `1` `s`econd ago (the idea being to get those with a modification time in the future), find the `srt` files (with an optional `.xx` before it) with the same root name, take the oldest (`Om` to `O`rder by modification time) and copy its mtime to that of the mkv.

(BTW, your *`oldest=( $dir/*.(|srt|)(N.Om[1]) )`* should rather be `oldest=( $dir/*.srt(N.Om[1]) )`. *`(|srt|)`* means *nothing* or `srt` or *nothing*).

Comment: As I said in other  thread its not working, for f (**/*.mkv) touch -r $f:r.srt -- $f
touch: failed to get attributes of 'Exit.festival.2022/Exit.festival.2022.srt': No such file or directory. To edit my post I found out why many subtitles have code suffices like .hr.srt on the end or sr.srt or br.srt and its because of that

Comment: @Loop1, see edit.

Comment: Great your edited script working like a charm.